# Windows File Explorer won't show certain drive letters

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, drive-letter

Title says it,

The missing/hidden drive letter was `G:/`

I'd tried all possible cause of the issue, The drive letter was first used by GoogleDriveFS, but since I've moved it to `Z:/` Now Now if I insert a new drive, it assigns to `G:/`, but hidden, *(same results on 3rd party file explorers, but shows as DiskMgmt/CompMgmt)*

*PS. It is not about the letter of the drive, It is more of the **Visiblility** of the letter on file explorer*

Comment: Unclear: You have moved `G:` to `Z:` and expect `G:` to still exist?

Comment: Nope, `G:` doesnt show up in the first place, I thought moving the GoogleDriveFS will clear what the cause of the bug/etc.

Comment: Why would `G` show up if it doesn't contain anything?

Comment: please kindly check my new answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the cause,

Some utilities/tweaks cause the "Certain" letter to not exist,

In this registry path: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDrive` is the cause of the problem, it was set to `64` that corresponds to letter `G:/`

For reference to "How to hide/unhide" a certain letter, here is the [site](https://winaero.com/hide-drive-windows-10-file-explorer/)